# Pandas data frame - filter rows by values from another data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have two pandas data frames, that their relevant columns are:

*stimuli* data frame:

```
   stimuli_id    rank         
0     23          0  
1     27          1 
2     62          2 
3     88          2 
4     99          1
```

while 'stimuli_id' is a unique index, and 'rank' is a integer in range of [0,2].
Relevant columns from *trials* data frame is:

```
     stim1     stim2        
0     23         27
1     27         62   
2     62         99
```

While both stim1 and stim2 represent stimuli_id from *stimuli* data frame.

Now I want to filter all rows in trials data frame where the rank of the second stimuli is greater.
So the example above after filtering should look like this:

```
       stim1     stim2        
0       62         99
```

So eventually only for this trial stim1 is greater than stim2, and the rest are not so we filter them.

I have tried the following:

```
trials.loc[stimuli.loc[stimuli["stimuli id"] == trials["stim1"]].iloc[0]["rank"] > stimuli.loc[stimuli["stimuli id"] == trials["stim2"]].iloc[0]["rank"]]
```

But a value error has been raised:

```
{ValueError}Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

I have been searching for hours for any solution but found nothing helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `'stimuli_id'` is a unique key for that DataFrame, use the Series to `map` the different stim columns to ranks and check the comparison. (By "rank of the second stimuli is greater" I assume you mean a smaller number).

```
s = stimuli.set_index('stimuli_id')['rank']

trials[trials['stim2'].map(s) < trials['stim1'].map(s)]
#   stim1  stim2
#2     62     99
```

---

With mapping each column we are logically creating the mask with the following comparison:

```
#rank2      rank1
#    1   <      0   # False
#    2   <      1   # False
#    1   <      2   # True
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. However, if I want to keep those rows where stim1 has higher rank, but also stim1's rank is  2, how can I do that with this approach? I have tried adding this condition to the trials filtering but it didn't work.

Comment: @AlinaRya In that case you an add on an additional condition, the mask would be `(trials['stim2'].map(s) < trials['stim1'].map(s)) & trials['stim1'].map(s).eq(2)` So the first condition **and** the rank of the first is 2